# Reversing words in a string c

Tags: c

I am trying to reverse the words in a string , i started learning C just now so i tried that with things I know . Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char a[11] , b[11]  ;
    int i = 0  , j = 0 , x  , p = 0 , q =9  ;
    while ((a[j++] = getchar()) != '\n') ;
    a[10] = '\0' ;
    while (p < 11 )
    {
        b[q] = a[p] ;
        q-- ;
        p++ ;
    }

    j = 0 ;
    while (j < 10)
    {
        ++i  ;
        ++j ;
        if (a[j] == ' ' || a[j] == '\0')
        {
            for (x = j  ; x >= (j - i) ; x--)
                printf("%c" , b[x]) ;
            i = 0 ;
        }
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

There is an unexpected '=' . 
like my name is
 is name =my

Please make the required corrections.

Comment: Can you give an example of the current input and the output?

Comment: `while ((a[j++] = getchar()) != '\n') ;` <- reimplementing `gets()`? (Hint: there's a buffer overflow ahead)

Comment: I suggest to start over. Functions to use: `fgets()` for getting the input sentence, `strtok()` for splitting it in parts (read: words), `malloc()` for allocating an output string of the same size, `strcat()` for concatenating the words in reverse order.

Comment: @Wimmel Input - my name is
Output -  is name =my

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just accept single strings here is the code,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char myString[50],newString[50];
   int index1=0,index2=0,tmpIndex;

   printf("Enter a string:\n");
   scanf("%s",&myString);
   printf("Entered String:%s\n",myString);


   while(myString[index2]!= '\0')
   {
     index2=index2+1;
   }
   tmpIndex=index2;

   printf("Original String Lenght=%d\n",tmpIndex);
   printf("Reversing String....\n");

   index2=index2 - 1;//To not to copy the '\0' of original string
   while(index1 < tmpIndex)
   {
     newString[index1]=myString[index2];
     //printf("%c\n",newString[index1]);
     index1++;
     index2--;
   }
   newString[index1] = '\0';//finally at the end of string add '\0' 
   printf("\n%s",newString);
   printf("\nNew string Lenght:%d",index1);
 }
```

For accepting strings with spaces in between here is the code,(Just use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`.)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char myString[50],newString[50];
   int index1=0,index2=0,tmpIndex;

   printf("Enter a string:\n");
   fgets(myString,50,stdin);
   printf("Entered String:%s\n",myString);


   while(myString[index2]!= '\n')
   {
     index2=index2+1;
   }
   tmpIndex=index2;

   printf("Original String Lenght=%d\n",tmpIndex);
   printf("Reversing String....\n");

   index2=index2 - 1;//To not to copy the '\0' of original string
   while(index1 < tmpIndex)
   {
    newString[index1]=myString[index2];
    //printf("%c\n",newString[index1]);
    index1++;
    index2--;
   }
   newString[index1] = '\0';//finally at the end of string add '\0' 
   printf("\n%s",newString);
   printf("\nNew string Lenght:%d",index1);
}
```